# Test Loop malfunctioning

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a loop to adjust the intensity of a laser. I am using a dummy variable just to check and see if the code works but the program does not work as intended.

The code sets the laser to .2A but does not change.

Here's the code I've tried:

```cs
private void AdjustIntensity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double setLDCurr;
    var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    {
        int testVariable = 199;
        if (testVariable < 200)
        {
            //dummy Current value
            setLDCurr = 0.2;
            laser.setLdCurrSetpoint(setLDCurr);
            testVariable++;
        }
        else if (testVariable >= 200)
        {
            //dummy Current value
            setLDCurr = 0.3;
            laser.setLdCurrSetpoint(setLDCurr);
            testVariable++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int testVariable = 199` on every loop it is always 199  **[How to use the built-in, awesome Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Ah true, would this be fixed if I define the variable above the while loop and place testVariable++; outside of the if loops but within the while loop?

Comment: It would take less time to test that change than to write the question. You only need to move the declaration and initialization of `testVariable` before the `while` loop. Moving `testVariable++` (and `laser.setLdCurrSetpoint(setLDCurr);`) after the `if/else` will reduce repetitive code, but won't affect the outcome.

Comment: Also, instead of doing math in your `while` condition on each iteration, you could instead just calculate the `endTime` once and compare the current time to that: `var endTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5); while (DateTime.UtcNow < endTime) { }`

Answer (score 1):

You kept declaring testVariable within the loop and resetting its value. You also iterated it within the if and else if statements which was redundant because no value will cause an if else exception. The exact time to detect change in time seems like overkill, I'm not sure how important speed is and how long a process DateTime.UctNow is. Also, if the purpose of this is to switch the laser intensity based on number of iterations, it might be better to not use testVariable and instead use the time span.

```
double setLDCurr;
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
int testVariable = 199;

while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
{
   if (testVariable < 200)
   {
      //dummy Current value
      setLDCurr = 0.2;
      laser.setLdCurrSetpoint(setLDCurr);
   }
   else
   {
      //dummy Current value
      setLDCurr = 0.3;
      laser.setLdCurrSetpoint(setLDCurr);
   }
   testVariable++;
}
```

edit: thanks Rufus L

```
double setLDCurr;
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
int testVariable = 199;
while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
{
   laser.setLdCurrSetPoint(testVariable++ < 200 ? 0.2 : 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Or the body of the `while` loop could just be one line: `laser.setLdCurrSetPoint(testVariable++ < 200 ? 0.2 : 0.3);`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. Could you expand on how the while loop is written in one line?   laser.setLdCurrSetPoint(testVariable++ < 200 ? 0.2 : 0.3); - how does that take into account both conditions, >=200 or <200?

Comment: the conditional operator has two Boolean options. Since you have two options (the number is either greater than 200 or not), the output is either .2 or .3. So testvariable is incremented, the condition is __ < 200, if yes the output is 0.2, if no the output is 0.3. Check the link if that's not clear [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)